# Tell application next track inside repeat

Tags: applescript

I am trying to define script to play next on iTunes an Spotify like this.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set apps to ("Spotify", "iTunes")
    repeat with thisApp in apps
        tell application thisApp
            next track
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

But on the `tell` block, I keep getting: "Expected end of line but found identifier."

How can I use application's name as iterable var in this case?

Comment: Just use, `tell application "Spotify" to next track` **and** `tell application "iTunes" to next track`

Comment: Of course it's possible, I am just curious how to solve the problem of tell block, what if some cases where the repeat loop is more than just 2 items?

Comment: You cannot use a `repeat` _loop_ in the specific manner you're trying, regardless of how many App names are in the list. You always have to use either `tell application ...` or `using terms from application ...` while using the actual application name, not a variable name, otherwise the script will not compile and get an error.

Answer (score 1):

This format will work:

```
set apps to {"Spotify", "iTunes"}
repeat with thisApp in apps
    if (thisApp's contents = "Spotify") then
        tell application "Spotify" to next track
    else if (thisApp's contents = "iTunes") then
        tell application "iTunes" to next track
    end if
end repeat
```